# Menu that accepts single character in C language

Tags: c, menu

I want to create a simple menu in C program that accepts single character. The menu will be like this:

1. [S]how
2. [E]xit

If the user enter '1','s' or 'S' the program will print "Hello" and prompt again for the input
else if the user enters '2',E or 'E' the program ends.
else it should print "invalid input" and prompt again.

I am able to create the program but the problem is that when user enters 12, 13, 14, 15, 16.....so on starting with 1, it shows Hello and same for other options.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clearBuffer();


int main() {

    int i = 0;
    char selection;

    do
    {
        printf("\t1. [S]how\n");
        printf("\t2. [E]xit\n");
        printf("Enter your selection from the number or character noted above: ");
        scanf("%s", &selection);
        clearBuffer();

        if (selection == '1' || selection == 's' || selection == 'S')
            printf("Hello");
        else if (selection == '2' || selection == 'E' || selection == 'x')
            i = 0;

 } while(i != 0);



}

void clearBuffer()
{   

    while(getchar() != '\n');

}
```

Comment: There comes a point when working with user interfaces (even in character mode) when you're likely to need I/O functions that aren't in the standard library. If this is a learning exercise, you might look to platform-specific functions or a portable API that supports more immediately interactive I/O. In practice, you're probably better off with a portable library like `curses` that IIRC will handle your menus for you - though I've not used it myself. I once wrote a text-mode UI library for Turbo Pascal (many people did - reinventing the wheel was a popular hobby), but I don't recommend it.

Comment: `curses` would actually be a great library to use for a menu system, but it does take a bit more than what the OP is doing here. If the OP is comfortable working with libraries and doing all the other setup/cleanup involved with `curses`, then by all means, yeah, go for it. This looks more like a homework assignment, and I'm not terribly sure if s/he is that far along programming-wise.
@user521815 : how comfortable are you with C programming at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [strlen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlen), which is part of the standard C library, to check the length of the string returned by scanf and reject entries longer than one character:

```
if (strlen(selection) > 1)
{
    printf("Invalid selection.");
}
```

Alternatively, I think you could use getchar() to accept just a single character from the user, which means they wouldn't have to press enter.

Comment: You still have to press enter with `getchar()`

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to receive only one character consider replacing the scanf() function for **getchar()** function:

```
printf("Enter your selection from the number or character noted above: "); 
selection = getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you should use `getchar()` if you only want one character. If you still want to use `scanf()` for whatever reason you may have, the correct format is `"%c"`, not `"%s"`.

I would also suggest that if you are looking for a single character, the `if` block looks a little "busy" (read, awkward) ... a switch would be a cleaner, more elegant way to do it (IMHO).

```
/* something like this ... */
switch ( selection ) {
  case '1':
  case 's':
  case 'S':
    printf ( "Hello\n" );
    break;

  case '2':
  case 'e':
  case 'E':
    i = 0;
    break;
}
```

Other couple of things ... if you don't care about the case of the character being read (that is, `'s'` and `'S'` will do the same thing), you can convert `selection` to uppercase before your `if`-block or `switch`-block using `toupper()`. Also, and this is just a style suggestion, don't use `i` for your exit flag. General practice is to use things like `i` and `j` for counters or indexes - you could use something like `quit_now` or `user_done` which would convey more precisely what the variable means.